# How to select a node based on its child's text value?

Tags: xpath

I want to select a node based on the text value of a child.
My structure is as follows (sorry for german nodes):

```
<InspizierteAbwassertechnischeAnlage>           
  <Objektbezeichnung>10502002</Objektbezeichnung>
  <Anlagentyp>1</Anlagentyp>
</InspizierteAbwassertechnischeAnlage>
```

How can I select the `<InspizierteAbwassertechnischeAnlage>` node where e.g. `<Objektbezeichnung>` = 10502002?

Comment: ancestor:://*[text()='10502002']
According to the docs this is the selector for ancestors, but it says invalid expression :/ (Sorry, but this is my first project with xpath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why your solution didn't work

`ancestor:://*[text()='10502002']` is syntactically incorrect, it's not valid XPath. I'm not sure what you tried to do with the axes here.

`//*[text()='10502002']` itself would just select the `Objektbezeichnung` itself and not its parent. It would also select any other element with such a value, regardless of its name. In case of this document, nothing redundant would be returned but you have to be careful when using wildcards (`*`)

### The solution

It's quite simple, you have to use a predicate to inspect the content of the child element

```
//InspizierteAbwassertechnischeAnlage[Objektbezeichnung = '10502002']
```

Note the double slash (`//` ), it is the [abbreviated syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)  for the `descendant-or-self` axis. The above expression translates to:

```
/descendant-or-self::InspizierteAbwassertechnischeAnlage[Objektbezeichnung = '10502002']
```

Or in plain English

> In the set of all descendants of the document's root, find `InspizierteAbwassertechnischeAnlage` elements that contain at least one `Objektbezeichnung` element with a value of `10502002`

As for German element names, at least it's not Hottentottenstottertrottelmutterbeutelrattenlattengitterkofferattentäter or Rhababerbarbarabarbarbarenbartbarbierbierbarbärbel

Comment: Excellent answer - the only piece of explanation I'd like to add is that the OP's own try didn't work because `*[text()='...']` would select the element that directly contains the indicated string (in this case `<Objektbezeichnung>` rather than the `<InspizierteAbwassertechnischeAnlage>` element.

Comment: Also, I *think* it should be a *Wetterkotter* instead of a *Koffer*, and finally a *Fangprämie* of all those ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper apologies, my German is pretty awful :)
Also, I think the OP's solution was syntactically incorrect to begin with. Notice the `descendant`